# Indefinite Hessian and concavity

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=x_1x_2x_3 - 2x_1^2-2x_3^2$, with $S:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3:-1<x<0\}$. I would like to see if $f$ is a convex function.

One way to determine it is to use the definition of concavity. So let $\theta\in [0,1]$, then

$$f(\theta x + (1-\theta)y)=\theta^3 x_1x_2x_3 - 2\theta^2 x_1^2 - 2\theta^2 x_3^3+(1-\theta)^2 x_1x_2x_3 - 2(1-\theta)^2 x_1^2 - 2(1-\theta^2) x_3^2\ge \theta(x_1x_2x_3-2x_1^2-2x_3^2)+(1-\theta)(y_1y_2y_3-2y_1^2-2y_3^2)=\theta f(x)+(1-\theta)f(y)$$

From which one can see that $f$ is not convex. But not convex does not imply concavity.

Now consider the Hessian matrix of $f$:

\begin{bmatrix}
-4 & x_3 & x_2\\ 
x_3 & 0 & x_1\\ 
x_2 & x_1  & -4
\end{bmatrix}

Here $D_1=-4, D_2=-x_3^2, D_3=4x_1^2+4x_3^2+2x_1x_2x_3$, so it follows that $D_3\ge 0$, whereas $D_1, D_2\le 0$, so that $H_f$ is indefinite. As far as I understand this implies that $f$ can have a saddle shape.

From both approaches one can say the function is not convex, but what can one conclude about the shape of the graph of $f$? I think we can say that it is not concave using the Hessian approach, or can we?

Would appreciate your insight.

Comment: the function is easy to draw when you fix $x_2$

Comment: What are $D_1$, $D_2$ and $D_3$? If they are the first partial derivatives, they don't look correct.

Comment: @Ernie060 they are leading principal minors

Comment: Aha! That's clarifies it. Thank you, @LinAlg!

Comment: @LinAlg I can draw it, but how can I make a conclusion about the concavity of the function from the Hessian matrix analysis?

Comment: @sequence as $H_f$ is indefinite, the function cannot be concave (as a concave function has a negative semidefinite hessian)

Comment: @LinAlg I'm wondering if it would be possible to show that the inequality analysis above could lead to a different inequality sign with the same RHS and LHS. Then does this mean that the inequality analysis is inconclusive? Also, the graph of the function shows that it is concave, whichever $x_2$ you take in the range. Or is it not?

Comment: I do not understand the inequality analysis. Some powers seem incorrect, and the $\geq$ goes a bit fast for me.

Comment: @LinAlg All the terms are negative because $x\in (-1, 0)$, and the powers were "eliminated" because, for example, $\theta^3 = \theta  \theta  \theta \le \theta$, since $\theta \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @sequence and still there has to be a mistake in the $\geq$ part, because you prove that the function is convex while Red shows has showed that it is not.

Answer (score 1):

It is not convex because on the path $$x_1 =t , \quad x_2 =x_3 = -\frac{1}{2}  , \quad t \in (-1 ,0)$$    is not convex.

It is not concave because on the path $$x_1 =t^2 -1 , \quad x_1 =x_3 = -\frac{1}{2} , \quad t \in (0 ,1)$$  in not concave.

Comment: Does this mean that it is a saddle? Also does this mean that the inequality analysis does not give a conclusive answer in this case?